# PHP Timesheet calculate past 24hrs

Tags: javascript, php, time

I'm trying to calculate a timesheet i'm working on within a JS onChange event, the following works but it wont work past midnight, for example 23:00 - 01:00 returns 22 instead of 2 or rather 2.00 as I'd like it to report to 2 decimal places.

```
$startm = date_create({mS}); //create a php datetime object
$finishm = date_create({mF});
$t_diff = date_diff($startm, $finishm); //calculate the difference
{mT} = $t_diff->h + round($t_diff->i/60,2) + {mOt} + {mOt2} /24; //add everything up
```

The form has the following fields

```
    Start Tme = mS - 24hr time 
    Finish Time = mF - 24hr time
    Overtime = mOt - int
    Overtime 2 = mOt2 - int
    Total = mT - int
```

Comment: If the second time is smaller than the first time add one date to it before doing your diff

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a check if `$startm` is past noon and `$finishm` is NOT past noon, `$total -= 12`. This of course won't work for shifts that last more than 24 hours, but that doesn't seem to be an acceptance criteria for your code.